# Is there some quick GUI or command line to test a model logic?

Tags: c#, software-testing, debugging

I'm writing a sim game model, the ui layer is undermined(Unity, Godot...), now it's using a winform.

The model consists dozens of scripts, hundreds of methods. When I want to **test the model logic**, it's a lot of work to write proper GUI, even using winform.

Is there some good package, which offers some quick way to generate GUI or command line, that can find objects and invoke methods? It's quite like a **in-app debugger**.

Can some c# package do this?

I'll write a simple tree transverse object listing and reflection based invoking form soon.
Just wonder what would a experienced C# programmer do, testing their model logic.